# Achieve a WPF overlay like in EA Origin

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay

How can I achieve an overlay, similar to the one you can see in the picture linked below, using C# and WPF?

[image: EA Origin overlay example]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't that just a window shown when you mouse over? Capture on mouse enter/leave of where you want it to spawn from and show/hide the window on event.

Comment: I don't exactly know if it's just a new window, I'd like it to be transparent where the control beneath is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a window to transparent just do either of the following: Window.Background="Transparent", or Opacity="0". As far as how it pops up, either handle mouse enter yourself or set it up as a popup

Comment: In your window code, 
this.Opacity = value; // 0.0 - 1.0 (double)
this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) Class. Your other option would be to create a [custom UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx).

---

After reading your comment you may want to look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949111/479512) it discusses using [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx)'s to create something like you are looking for.